error open image Node.js when request the second time
I'm trying to use Node to capture a screenshot of the user's screen on all displays and save everything in just one image, so far everything works fine if I call it the first time, but if I try to call it a second time without restarting the server, An error appears saying that the file cannot be opened.
Because I wanted to be able to make several requests to the screenshot, any ideas what I can do?
I'm still integrating with Node and JS so I don't know how it works very well.
Code:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  hello = 'Hello World!';
  console.log(hello);
  res.send(hello);
});

app.get('/screenshot', (req, res) => {
  const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop');
  const sharp = require('sharp');

  screenshot.listDisplays().then((displays) => {
    let screenshots = [];
    displays.forEach((display, i) => {
      const screenshotPath = `screenshot${i}.png`;
      screenshot({ screen: display.id }).then((imgBuffer) => { 
        fs.writeFile(screenshotPath, imgBuffer, (err) => { 
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Screenshot salvo!');
          screenshots.push(screenshotPath);
          if (screenshots.length === displays.length) {
            // Todas as screenshots foram salvas, agora junte-as
            Promise.all([
              sharp(screenshots[1]).metadata(),
              sharp(screenshots[0]).metadata()
            ]).then(([metadata1, metadata2]) => {
              sharp(screenshots[1])
                .extend({
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: metadata2.width,
                  background: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0 }
                })
                .composite([{ input: screenshots[0], left: metadata1.width, top: 0 }])
                .toBuffer()
                .then((buffer) => {
                  let base64Image = `data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString('base64')}`;
                  res.send(base64Image);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            }).catch(err => console.error(err));
          }
        });
      }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando em http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Error im getting and Log:
Servidor rodando em http://localhost:3000
Screenshot salvo!
Screenshot salvo!
F:\Andre\sk-access-control-ai\facialRecog\server.js:23
          if (err) throw err;
                   ^

[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'facialRecog\screenshot0.png'] {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'facialRecog\\screenshot0.png'
}

Node.js v20.12.2


I tried to create it like this, but instead of replacing the file, I would delete it and create a new one, but it would give me the error error eperm operation not permitted unlink saying that I can't delete a file, but I'm not using it nowhere, and I can only delete it when I close the localhost:3000 server

Maybe your process is still holding a lock on that file?

and how can I "unlock" it?
Even after the process is complete, if I call the function again, it remains "blocked" on it.
